# What is toggle_selector.RS

Tags: python, matplotlib

Im having trouble understanding what does that toggle_selector.RS mean in the toggle _selector. I have already read through the documentation but still not able to understand it. Could anyone please simply tell me what does that mean and how it works? Thanks in advance.

Example code:

```
def toggle_selector(event):
   toggle_selector.RS.set_active(True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
for n,image_file in enumerate(os.scandir(image_folder)):
    img = image_file
    fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)
    image = cv2.imread(image_file.path)
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    ax.imshow(image)
    toggle_selector.RS = RectangleSelector(
        ax,line_select_callback,
        drawtype="box" , useblit=True,
        button=[1] , minspanx=5, minspany=5,
        spancoords='pixels', interactive=True
    )
    bbox = plt.connect('key_press_event',toggle_selector)
    key = plt.connect('key_press_event',onkeypress)
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is exploiting the fact that Python functions are objects and stashing an instance of a `RectangleSelector` (https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/api/widgets_api.html#matplotlib.widgets.RectangleSelector) on the function `toggle_selector`.  It then registers a call back so that when you press a key, the selector is activated (meaning it will process your mouse events).

From the names, I'm guessing that the `line_select_callback` pulls out a line-cut from the image and displays it someplace else?

```py
def toggle_selector(event):
   toggle_selector.RS.set_active(True)
import numpy as np
img = np.random.rand(5, 5)
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.imshow(img)
toggle_selector.RS = RectangleSelector(
    ax,lambda *args, **kwargs: print(args, kwargs),
    drawtype="box" , useblit=True,
    button=[1] , minspanx=5, minspany=5,
    spancoords='pixels', interactive=True
)
bbox = plt.connect('key_press_event',toggle_selector)
plt.show()
```

is a more minimal version.  I am however a bit confused as to *why* it is doing this from the code provided because the `RectangleSelector` is active when created by default.

Comment: thx for the explanation. So is it fine if I delete toggle_selector function as well?

Comment: You will need to keep a reference to the `RectangleSelector` someplace.  If you do not it will get garbage collected and you will lose the interactivity.